# How do you stim Marines while also controlling a Raven?

Tags: starcraft-2

If you click on your army consisting of say marines and raven only, the symbols in the right corner, for the special abilities will be the ones for the raven (point defense drone and so on), i.e. one cannot stim the marines.

My question is: Is there a fast possibility of changing those symbols, so that you can stim your marines while still controlling also your raven (without using groups)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Press tab to cycle through different unit groups while keeping them all selected.

Comment: Is there some way when you make a control group to have some units come up "first" and be readily accessible without tabbing?

Comment: @NickT No.  Every time you re-access the control group it will be put in some kind of default order.  Generally, casters are first.

Comment: @NickT Alternatively, you can assign the subgroup to a separate control group to make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would say keeping rines and ravens in 1 group and following 'pressing' tab is very APM un-effective... very often when you detect marines been attacked you want just do "1-t" (if your marines are in 1 group #1, or any group number, doesn't matter).

If you will don't have this habit yet 1-tab-t, you will often go into situation "1-t"....and nothing... and 't-t-t-t'... and 1-tab-t - .. and figure out that instead of stemming your rines you will putting turret from raven... YOu need to press 'esc+tab+t'... but it is too late: you lost 2-3 seconds during which zerlings/mutas killed either half of your marines or your raven...

**I would recommend to have ravens on another control group** (***if you like using '1' for marines, redefine 0 to '`' - key left to '1' and use it for ravens***). Another option is to change short cut for either 'stim' or 'turret', but 1) not sure if this is possible; 2) not sure if this is really good idea (you will still need to press 'tab')... :(